# Allow downloading of INI files in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My website on Debian 9 doesn't allow to download any .ini files located in any folders. How to allow downloading of .ini files at least from a specific folder using .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally find where and how these files are being blocked as it may require additional steps to "unblock". However, you can try something like the following in the `.htaccess` file in the directory that you want to permit access to all `.ini` files:

```
<Files "*.ini">
Require all granted
</Files>
```

---

**Update from OP:**

In `error.log` I see the following:

> ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched phrase ".ini/" at TX:extension.

I can solve this problem by adding a new directive for Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRuleRemoveByTag CWAF
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Regrettably it doesn't work. I don't know what setting causes this issue. Earlier with Debian 8 it worked fine.

Comment: What response do you get? 403 Forbidden? Are .htaccess overrides enabled? Do you have other directives in .htaccess that are active?

Comment: Yes, 403 Forbidden for any .ini files.
I added a new .htaccess for current folder (no other directives). I forgot about overrides. Can you post a sample code?

Comment: ... include some _nonsense_ at the start of the `.htaccess` file, do you get an error? If not, then `.htaccess` overrides are not enabled (ie. `.htaccess` is not enabled). You would need to add `AllowOverride All` to the appropriate `<Directory>` container in the associated `<VirtualHost>` (or main server config, if no vHosts are configured).

Comment: In error.log I see the following:
"ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Matched phrase ".ini/" at TX:extension."

Comment: I can solve this problem by adding a new directive for Apache & NGINX:
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRuleRemoveByTag CWAF
</IfModule>

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - glad you got it resolved.. I've added your comments to my answer (since the question appears to have been closed, so it won't accept more answers) - as this could help other readers.

Comment: Thanks for your willing help!